# Caching data using $cacheFactory vs regular javascript variable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

The InvoiceModel below has a getByCustomer() function that lists the invoices for a given customer.

I'm just wondering what's the difference between caching data to a regular javascript variable compared to using $cacheFactory.

Regular Javascipt Variable:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Invoice', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://foo.bar/invoices');
    }
])
.factory('InvoiceModel', ['Invoice',
    function(Invoice) {
        var customer_invoices = [];

        return {
            getByCustomer: function(customer_id) {
                if (customer_invoices[customer_id] == undefined) {
                    customer_invoices[customer_id] = Invoice.get({customer_id: customer_id});
                }

                return customer_invoices[customer_id];
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

$cacheFactory

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Invoice', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://foo.bar/products');
    }
])
.factory('InvoiceModel', ['Invoice', '$cacheFactory',
    function(Invoice, $cacheFactory) {
        var customerInvoicesCache = $cacheFactory('customerInvoicesCache');

        return {
            getByCustomer: function(customer_id) {
                var invoices = customerInvoicesCache.get(customer_id);

                if (!invoices) {
                    customerInvoicesCache.put(Invoice.get({customer_id: customer_id}));
                }

                return invoices;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `$cacheFactory` in the fashion you have shown. You're kind of using it the way [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) would use it internally.

Instead, you can configure an `$http` or `$resource` object to cache the responses for specific queries. You then merely use the `$http` or `$resource` as normal. It handles the caching for you.

**Example with `$resource`:**

```
.factory('Invoice', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://foo.bar/products', {}, {
            query: { cache: true }
        });
    }
])
```

The above overrides the query method of the resource to enable caching with the default `$cacheFactory`. The first time your code calls the query method the response will get cached. Any subsequent calls to the query method will use the cached response.

**Example with `$http`:**

```
$http.get('/the-url', { cache: true }).then(...)
// or by passing in your own cache factory
var cache = $cacheFactory('myCacheFactory');
$http.get('/the-url', { cache: cache }).then(...);
```

**Clearing the cache:**

When you need to clear the cache, you get the `$cacheFactory` and call it's [remove()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) function to clear the cache for the associated URL:

```
// default cache factory
var defaultCache = $cacheFactory('$http');
defaultCache.remove('/some/url');
// custom cache factory
var cache = $cacheFactory('myCacheFactory');
cache.remove('/custom-cache-url');
```